# Who's digging up dirt in the close queue?

Tags: discussion, review, closing

The close queue contains an extremely large number of old, answered (accepted) and downvoted questions.

Even if these questions *should* have been closed, some of them now have a good answer worth keeping and should instead be edited (if necessary).

<s>The respective user seems not to have sufficient privileges for voting to close themselves so I can't identify him/her.</s>

@All Reviewers: Please keep an eye on the timestamp and check if the question has an answer worth keeping. If so, please consider editing the question to raise it to Math.SEs quality standards and vote to leave open.

Comment: What's the point of this?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I have no idea how to bring this to anyone's attention other than this format. Note that the respective user is unidentifiable by me and causes harm to the site in some way (at least in my opinion).

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with letting old, bad questions stay on the site simply because they're old.  That would be like letting old people rob banks and get away with it simply because they're old. :)  (Ok, it's not really the same, but I thought it was funny and kind-of similar.)

Comment: @anorton The point is that the questions actually _have_ good answers. Instead of closing them, they could be edited (a few at a time) to make better questions with good answers.

Comment: 'Q: How many sides does a dot have?' 'A:  A "dot" on my monitor appears to be a square comprised of four pixels. Therefore, a dot has four sides.' This is useful?

Comment: @quid I shall revoke a categorical, but some of these _do_ have good answers. Can't look into the queue right no because my votes are used up, but I saw a majority of the questions actually had good answers.

Comment: The age of the question is not important, the quality is.

Comment: You should be able to access the [review history](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) even if you don't have reviews left.

Comment: @quid, apparently six people found it useful.  In fact, the OP accepted the answer. :P

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Obviously it is useful, as a good laugh during a hard day can be quite useful.:D Still it should not have a permanent place on this site, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @quid This particular instance, yes. However some questions might be worth saving. I'll reword the question to reflect that, since deletion is no longer possible.

Comment: Sure. Some might be worth preserving. This is why we have that review, where one  can vote "leave open."// I see you edited the post in that sense already.

Comment: @quid Yes, but it doesn't show you the answers you vote to auto-delete for, which is what I'm trying to hint at.

Comment: It shows though if there are answers, and if there is an accepted one. (In addition if there are highly scored answers there is no *auto*-delete.) I will concede though that one might miss that aspect. This design however hints at the fact that the answer-based approach here is against the spirit of the site.

Comment: @AlexR This has been happening for a long time - going back to at least 7 months ago when [user147263's](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/147263/famous-blue-raincoat) massive [deletion campaign](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/15133/242) started gaining steam. It's the same small group of users behind all of this massive destruction. If this continues unchecked, then more than half of the site's content will be deleted, including many good answers. The only way to stop this is to closely monitor closures and deletions and reverse them when appropriate. Alas, it seems few users do so.

Comment: Few users,  500+ new questions per day, half the site deleted. Given that votes are limited, something does not work out here.

Comment: @quid There were far fewer questions per day in the early days, and the user behind that campaign has been exploiting many different SE loopholes.

Comment: @quid Regardless of the exaggerations, Bill does have a point there. Even a few lost questions with nice answers are undesirable and justify the additional caution I plea for.

Comment: @BillDubuque if "the content" is measured by question-threads, it can *never* reach "more than half" if the current number of deletion is not larger than the *current* number of new questions. If you want to measure it in some other way please specify it.

Comment: @quid I'm talking about past posts (like the OP), esp. posts composed in much earlier times when the majority opinion on question standards greatly differed from nowadays (before the site was so swamped that users started trying to address the swamping via altering question quality standards).

Comment: @BillDubuque you just said "then more than half of the site's content will be deleted" It now seems that you agree this statement at least needs some qualification regarding the time-span during which the content was created. Thus, I would like to ask you to exercise more care when making such claims and to include qualifications as needed right away.

Comment: @quid The site's content does not, of course, refer to the future content. Enough on this tangent.

Comment: These recent comments remind me of the problem about putting many balls in and few out, but infinitely often and in order, to end up with nothing left: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7063/a-problem-of-an-infinite-number-of-balls-and-an-urn.

Comment: @Jonas Or paradoxical decompositions of MSE.

Comment: There is a difference between a mathematically correct question and a what is considered as good.I don't think adding a mostly wrong trial to a mathematically correct and complete question improves it. While a background (if availble) can improve the question. So it can arguable which questions are good. Another problem is that what will change if a on old question is closed.

Comment: @quid ever since Bill's massive anti-deletion campaign started months ago, half the meta questions on the site now contain material on that very campaign ;)

Comment: @rschwieb Please ... we don't need more strawmen on meta.

Comment: @BillDubuque Neither do we need non sequitur high school debate team objections. It's called *satire*, and if you think it sounds silly then you should consider what it's inspiration sounded like.

Comment: On 26 June 2014, a month after the account 147263 was created, [there were questions 298,556 on MSE](https://web.archive.org/web/20140626233027/http://math.stackexchange.com/questions). Of these, [there are 288,898 left](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/272788). That's a difference of 9,658. Even assuming that *all of these* were deleted because of FBR's actions (a ludicrous assumption, as anyone involved even a little bit with moderation knows), that's 3.2% in eight months. Since this is a math website, I'd rather not insult you by spelling out the conclusion (compare 3.2 and 50).

Comment: @Najib You miss the point (again), which is that a large portion of the old content will eventually be deleted due to not meeting future "quality standards". But go on attacking your strawman and enjoying the upvotes you get by doing so.

Comment: @Bill If everyone (at least 12 people) misses your point, you might want to start looking for the common factor. Anyway, I call argumentum ad abracadabrum and declare the debate over.

Comment: @Najib The usual suspects hardly comprise "everyone". My point stands. No doubt you'd attempt to argue with me if I wrote $1+1 =2.\,$ Argument for the sake of argument is fruitless.

Comment: I don't know if it was only me, but I started the close votes on the sides of a dot question.  I voted to close exactly 12 old questions yesterday.  Either this is the "extremely large number," or we're talking about more than one user.  Of the 12, 11 are now on hold, 8 of them with the help of a close vote from AlexR.  They can all be found in the review history to be reopened for those inclined and with 3000+.

Comment: @JonasMeyer While 12 is indeed a lot for one time, there were almost 30 if I can recall correctly, only very few of them being younger than a month.

Comment: I didn't see any other old ones in the review queue during the relevant time period.  You do not have to recall if you would like to check for evidence in the review history, in case it is relevant that there be more than 12.

Comment: @JonasMeyer To me this is absolutely irrelevant, the sheer number just triggered an alarm with me which lead me to post this question. Judging from the many votes on this question (23 currently) and the fact that it was clopened, the subject is indeed very controversial.

Comment: @AlexR: OK, that was supposed to be in response to your mentioning the number much larger than 12, so I didn't know it was absolutely irrelevant.  It seems relevant that no one is making efforts to edit or reopen these questions (except one was left open).

Comment: @JonasMeyer Well, they _do_ require some effort to be eligible for re-opening (as in a substantial edit). Personally I voted to leave open those which I think are better off open, but I'm too lazy to improve the questions right now - I have to mind my own business.

Comment: I don't understand what harm is being claimed.

Comment: @BillDubuque If you don't want people disagreeing with you, avoid making overstatements. It's been a while since this "campaign" started and the evidence is the effect is quite negligible. Most delete questions are not questions we'll miss. People can stand apocalyptic preaching for so long.

Comment: @Pedro We'll have to agree to disagree on the evidence. I highly doubt that you've been paying as much attention to the deletion queue as have I. I'm not aware of any "overstatements", nor any "preaching".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Regarding the nature of the user

**From [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/201314):**

> Questions that may need closing/reopening appear in these queues. **Questions with active close votes or close flags show up in the close queue**, and questions with active reopen votes, as well as questions which have been edited after closing, appear in the reopen queue. Along with the moderator tools, this is one of the best ways to find posts that need closing.

*Emphasis mine*

Thus, it does not necessarily follow that the user has insufficient rep--they may have cast a single close vote and pushed it into the queue.

### Regarding the behavior of the user

Editing the question into shape is the best option.

*Personal opinion time!*
*I* think that simply "having a good answer" isn't sufficient to save a question--there are plenty of questions that have correct answers (but not uniquely special; for instance, evaluating $\int\frac{1}{1-y}\;dy$).  The answer may be good, but I see no value in keeping *every* evaluation of an elementary problem around on the site.  Hence, if I see a bad question with an "ok" (but not great) answer, I will tend to close it if I don't have time/energy to edit the question.

However, this is an **opinion-based issue.**  That's the reason why we actually have a close vote system, rather than allowing unilateral closure for average users.  I believe it will work itself out if enough people vote early and often.

Comment: If I'm the first one in the review list, the question can't have been pushed there with a close vote, _non_?

Comment: I think it's possible for a person to vote to close a question from the question itself, not from the review list, so even if you're the first person on the review list, it's possible that you're not the first person to vote to close.

Comment: @AlexR Actually, it could have been.  The review list history only shows the people who have *reviewed* the post, not the people who have *voted* on the post.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Oh, I thought a close vote on the post would show up in the review as well. At least the number of current close votes is a clear indicator, though?

Comment: I thought so too.  I think the number of current close votes takes into account all the close votes.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, the number of current close votes is an accurate indicator.  If there are no votes to close and the question is in the review queue, then either it was flagged, or there was a race-condition-like issue where someone retracted their closevote as you were loading the review. I've never seen the latter, though, so that's just speculation... :)